# Is the SWAT team led to a different building than Matthews by Jigsaw at the end of the film?

Tags: plot-explanation, saw, saw-2

Is the SWAT team led to a different building than Matthews by Jigsaw at the end of *Saw II* (2005)? It looks very similar to the actual crime scene, which is what confuses me so much. If it was the same building they would be able to find Matthews, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They discover that it's the same house but the video feed they are seeing is just previously recorded, it happened already. Danial was locked in a safe the whole time, that's why John was saying to just sit and talk.

Here's an excerpt of the plot from Wiki, emphasis mine:

> Having seen Xavier chasing his son, Eric brutally assaults John and forces him to lead him to the house. John's sitting area is revealed to be a lift, which they use to leave the factory. The tech team tracks the video's source and Rigg leads his team to a house, where they find **VCRs playing previously recorded images**. **As Kerry realizes the game took place before they found John**, the timer expires and a large safe opens, revealing Daniel bound and breathing into an oxygen mask. Eric enters the house alone and eventually locates the bathroom, where he is attacked by a pig-masked figure. He awakens shackled at the ankle to a pipe, and a tape recorder left by Amanda reveals that she is John's accomplice and intends to continue his work after he dies. Amanda suddenly appears in the doorway, and says "game over" before sealing the door, leaving Eric to die.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saw_II